# Deserializing json to a python object without actually save the object in DB

Tags: python, json, django, serialization, django-rest-framework

I use `Django` and the model classes to access data from `DB`. I would like to add cache layer on top of `DB`.

For example, let's say I have a User model and `UserSerializer` (inherited from `ModelSerializer`).
When storing an User object in cache, I need to `serialize` the object to `json`

```
import json
serializer = UserSerializer(obj)
serialized_data = json.dumps(serializer.data)
```

However, when I retrieve this json from cache, I had trouble to convert it back to User object

```
data = json.loads(serialized_data)
deserializer = UserSerializer(data=data)
user_obj = deserializer.save() # this return an User object but intenally it will create a new record in DB
```

Any better ideas that I can use the `serializer` that django provided to deserialize json to object without actually creating the record in **DB**?

Answer (score 0):

You can just use the model to create an object with the `serializer.validated_data` without actually saving it to the database:

```py
serializer = UserSerializer(data=data)
serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
user_obj = User(**serializer.validated_data)
```

However, it's important to note that you would have to manually deal with the ManyToMany relations, if your model have any and the serializer accepts them as a field.

If you have a `ManyToManyField` and don't want to manually deal with it, you can also call `deserializer.save()` in an [atomic transaction](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/transactions/#django.db.transaction.atomic) and raise an exception right after, which would create the `user_obj` variable without any changes being committed to the database:

```py
from django.db import transaction, NotSupportedError

serializer = UserSerializer(data=data)
serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
try:
    with transaction.atomic():
        user_obj = serializer.save()
        raise NotSupportedError
except NotSupportedError:
    pass
```